# Fit label text-size within the polygon Mapbox GL JS symbol-layer

Tags: labeling, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js, mapbox-gl

I want to make the text-label in the symbol layer fit within the polygon. Change the position and size of the text-label according to zoom and polygon. It is required for Mapbox GL JS.

```
const map = new mapboxgl.Map({
container: 'map',
style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/light-v9',
center: [-77.04, 38.907],
zoom: 11.15
});

const places = {
'type': 'FeatureCollection',
'features': [
    {
        'type': 'Feature',
        'properties': {
            'description': "Ford's Theater",
            'icon': 'theatre-15'
        },
        'geometry': {
            'type': 'Point',
            'coordinates': [-77.038659, 38.931567]
        }
    },
    {
        'type': 'Feature',
        'properties': {
            'description': 'The Gaslight',
            'icon': 'theatre-15'
        },
        'geometry': {
            'type': 'Point',
            'coordinates': [-77.003168, 38.894651]
        }
    },
    {
        'type': 'Feature',
        'properties': {
            'description': "Horrible Harry's",
            'icon': 'bar-15'
        },
        'geometry': {
            'type': 'Point',
            'coordinates': [-77.090372, 38.881189]
        }
    },
    {
        'type': 'Feature',
        'properties': {
            'description': 'Bike Party',
            'icon': 'bicycle-15'
        },
        'geometry': {
            'type': 'Point',
            'coordinates': [-77.052477, 38.943951]
        }
    },
    {
        'type': 'Feature',
        'properties': {
            'description': 'Rockabilly Rockstars',
            'icon': 'music-15'
        },
        'geometry': {
            'type': 'Point',
            'coordinates': [-77.031706, 38.914581]
        }
    },
    {
        'type': 'Feature',
        'properties': {
            'description': 'District Drum Tribe',
            'icon': 'music-15'
        },
        'geometry': {
            'type': 'Point',
            'coordinates': [-77.020945, 38.878241]
        }
    },
    {
        'type': 'Feature',
        'properties': {
            'description': 'Motown Memories',
            'icon': 'music-15'
        },
        'geometry': {
            'type': 'Point',
            'coordinates': [-77.007481, 38.876516]
        }
    }
]
};
map.on('load', () => {
// Add a GeoJSON source containing place coordinates and information.
map.addSource('places', {
    'type': 'geojson',
    'data': places
});

map.addLayer({
    'id': 'poi-labels',
    'type': 'symbol',
    'source': 'places',
    'layout': {
        'text-field': ['get', 'description'],
        'text-variable-anchor': ['top', 'bottom', 'left', 'right'],
        'text-radial-offset': 0.5,
        'text-justify': 'auto',
        'icon-image': ['get', 'icon']
    }
});
});
```

**Current scenario:**

[image]

**Desired output:**

[image]

Some sourced links to understand the question in a better way.

[How to show Labels on Geoserver, only if they fit within the Polygon?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/277912/how-to-show-labels-on-geoserver-only-if-they-fit-within-the-polygon)

[Reducing size of labels automatically to fit within polygons](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/108454/reducing-size-of-labels-automatically-to-fit-within-polygons)

https://support.esri.com/en/technical-article/000012903